# Search without consolidated exchange rate via SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

How do I create a saved search via SuiteScript 2.0 with consolidated exchange rate set to none? It's easy to do via the Saved Search UI (on results tab), however, I can't find a way to do this via SuiteScript.

Answer (score 3):

NetSuite finally included the settings attribute for search on SuiteScript 2.0

you just need to add this:

```
columns:[],
settings:[
    search.createSetting({
        name: "consolidationtype",
        value: "NONE"
    })
]
```

If you want, you can check the other settings available, at the API Reference Guide, section: search.createSetting(options)

https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSAPI/NSAPI.pdf

Comment: and this is not available in 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

Use the NetSuite Saved Search Export Chrome Extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-search-export/gglbgdfbkaelbjpjkiepdmfaihdokglp?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Since you already have the saved search, this is the easiest way to get the SuiteScript equivalent.

Comment: While this is a very useful tool (thanks!), the generated code does not include a way to turn off consolidated exchange rates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I found in case any one else is looking: You can create a saved search via the UI with the Consolidated Exchange Rate set to none and leave columns and filters empty. Then, all you need to do is load that saved search via script and specify the columns and filters. If you don't care about changing the columns or filters via script, you could also define them in the UI.